# Automatically update the filename in require(filename) if the name of a file is changed. (I'm using NeoVim)

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, neovim

I'm currently trying to learn nvim and node.js

Is there a way to automatically update the field in require (or imports in general) ?

I initially have

```
const x = require('./filaneme')
```

If I change *filename* to *anotherfilename*

Can I automatically have this result when reopening the js file in nvim?

```
const x = require('./anotherfilename')
```

the same with import filename from ...

Comment: I am not aware of such plugins or features.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on this [plugin](https://github.com/kristijanhusak/vim-js-file-import)

see if it's what you wanted